# Decoding Z64 (ZB64) string

Tags: c#, compression, lz77

I'm working on breaking down ZPL label definitions generated by NiceLabel label making software. For the most part I don't have to worry about decoding the Z64 because it is just encoded graphics and I don't need to change the underlying data.

However I have a line of text that is used as a graphic by the label for some reason probably due to Font's or something.

Anyways, the Z64 or ZB64 string is created by compressing the original data using LZ77 and encoding that as Base64 and then appending a CRC at the end.

TEST STRING FULL EXAMPLE:

```
:Z64:eJztkDFOxDAQRb81hRsULmBtruECyRwpZYpFGLmg5AhwFKMUuYal9CtL26QwHsbe3RMguv3lz9P85wD3/CWaiZ+56OjqWA44cwKIAyfeXXL1sQ7YWqd54czltTge+VOdOQsXFp8TrLUw9KEW3+6pLU4Zk3mC0ataonSEzU8JMywGCiFcue+c8YLGvYcLF5a+68WFhbvtRs5jdmVkWolj96vgXe/it7eucT+0+gxV5N5RrdTveQpevhnxO+BEfRe0xIzc/EbUzkn3lhLSIH6DdFeu+c39Hb7c7vksfrJryB8vu6A4cxE/NjpK1/6LkJZ3+nL1gaLt3D33/Ed+AehfkrY=:6C38
```

TEST STRING TARGET EXAMPLE:

```
eJztkDFOxDAQRb81hRsULmBtruECyRwpZYpFGLmg5AhwFKMUuYal9CtL26QwHsbe3RMguv3lz9P85wD3/CWaiZ+56OjqWA44cwKIAyfeXXL1sQ7YWqd54czltTge+VOdOQsXFp8TrLUw9KEW3+6pLU4Zk3mC0ataonSEzU8JMywGCiFcue+c8YLGvYcLF5a+68WFhbvtRs5jdmVkWolj96vgXe/it7eucT+0+gxV5N5RrdTveQpevhnxO+BEfRe0xIzc/EbUzkn3lhLSIH6DdFeu+c39Hb7c7vksfrJryB8vu6A4cxE/NjpK1/6LkJZ3+nL1gaLt3D33/Ed+AehfkrY=
```

My Code to Decode / Decompress:

```
static string DecompressZb64(string compressedString)
{
    var b64 = SmartWarehouse.Shared.Utils.Parser.ConvertFromBase64(compressedString);
    var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    var inBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b64);
    var outBytes = new byte[inBytes.Length];
    try
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            decompressionStream.Read(outBytes, 0, inBytes.Length);
        }

        return encoding.GetString(outBytes);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO: DOcument exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Current Exception:

```
Block length does not match with its complement.
```

Stacktrace:

```
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.DecodeUncompressedBlock(Boolean& end_of_block)
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Decode()
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at SmartWarehouse.Tools.Program.DecompressZb64(String compressedString) in C:\Users\[user_dir]\Source\Repos\Handheld.[user].[fork]\SmartWarehouse.Tools\Program.cs:line 511
```

UPDATE:

I was looking into this and I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771573/compressed-content-in-a-byte-array-to-uncompressed-in-a-string) it is essentially the same issue. So i did some more research and i found [this article on a blog from 2007](http://george.chiramattel.com/blog/2007/09/deflatestream-block-length-does-not-match.html). Which discusses a workaround by skipping the first 2 bytes in the input array due to those bytes not actually being included in the RFC specification.

CODE CHANGE:

```
static string DecompressZb64(string compressedString)
{
    var b64 = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedString);
    var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    var outBytes = new byte[b64.Length - 2];
    try
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(b64))
        {
            memoryStream.ReadByte();
            memoryStream.ReadByte();
            using (var decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                decompressionStream.Read(outBytes, 0, b64.Length - 2);
            }
        }

        return encoding.GetString(outBytes);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO: DOcument exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

This code change doesn't actually produce an exception anymore however it doesn't decompress properly and returns this result:

```
"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data looks fine to me, I got this image out of it:

[image]

It's a monochrome bitmap, one bit per pixel.

Your code didn't read until the end of the stream, there are actually 1280 bytes of image data, which can then be decoded to the image above.

Comment: This is totally correct, i found an implementation online that would allow me to read until the end of the stream. However it seems like I'm working to hard to create an image and then compress and encode it. I've opted to just replace the image with just a string and font that doesn't require conversion into an img. Thank you for your help, I've accepted your answer.

Comment: Do you know how to get the size and the row from this question? I tried [this post](https://codeutility.org/javascript-convert-zpl-base64-in-image-png-stack-overflow/) but I can not get the clear PNG file.

Comment: @ElaDute in this question, the row width was not included, I just guessed it. In other cases, it should be part of the draw command which preceded this data. For example in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67433507/555045) the row width (52 bytes, so 416 pixels) is included in the command.

Answer (score -2):

```
using System; 
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text; 
 

namespace ZB64Decode
{
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //this is C# 
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("^XA");
        sb.AppendLine("^UT1,1");
        sb.AppendLine("^Uh0,300,64,4000,2,0,F");
        sb.AppendLine("^Uh1,300,64,4000,2,0,F");
        sb.AppendLine("^UC1,0,1,0,0");
        sb.AppendLine("^LH0,0");
        sb.AppendLine("^LT0");
        sb.AppendLine("^XZ");
        sb.AppendLine("^XA");
        sb.AppendLine("^PW3543");
        sb.AppendLine("^LL512");
        sb.AppendLine("^FO532,66^GFA,885,9272,76,:Z64: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:718B");
        sb.AppendLine("^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ");
        var zpl = sb.ToString();
        
        //extract the Z64-String
        var z64Data = "";
        var bytesPerRow = 0;
        foreach (var item in zpl.Split('^'))
        {
            if (item.StartsWith("GFA"))
            {
                var sp= item.Split(':');
                z64Data = item.Substring(sp[0].Length);
                bytesPerRow = Convert.ToInt32(sp[0].Split(',')[3]);
                break;
            }
        }

        //convert String to Bitmap
        Bitmap decodedBitmap = null;
        if (z64Data.StartsWith(":Z64"))
        {
            var imageData = DecompressZb64(z64Data.Substring(5));

            int width = bytesPerRow * 8;
            int height = imageData.Length / bytesPerRow;

            decodedBitmap = ArrayToBitmap(imageData, width, height, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed); 
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(decodedBitmap.Width + ":" + decodedBitmap.Height);
    }
     

    public static Bitmap ArrayToBitmap(byte[] bytes, int width, int height, PixelFormat pixelFormat)
    {
        var image = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
        var imageData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
                          ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pixelFormat);
        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, imageData.Scan0, bytes.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            image.UnlockBits(imageData);
        }
        return image;
    }

    public static byte[] DecompressZb64(string compressedString)
    {
        var b64 = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedString.Split(':')[0]).Skip(2).ToArray();
        return Decompress(b64);
    }

    public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
    {
        byte[] decompressedArray = null;
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream decompressedStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (MemoryStream compressStream = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    using (DeflateStream deflateStream = new DeflateStream(compressStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        deflateStream.CopyTo(decompressedStream);
                    }
                }
                decompressedArray = decompressedStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do something !
        }

        return decompressedArray;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: explain your solution

Comment: You've got some C-Sharp code buried in there, professor. Specifically `using  ( [ Wrapper variable assignment ] )` is not valid Java.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.