# ZPL II decode Z64 (base64 and LZ77) to human readable text in Python

Tags: python-3.x, base64, zebra-printers, zpl-ii, lz77

I am trying to put together an app in python that will split a .prn file generated from Zebra Designer software containing thousands of labels in one file into single label files. I need to extract a highlighted below field and decode it to human readable form to use as names for the single label files. I have tried to decode base64 and decompress LZ77 as per instructions [here](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) on page 1435 that states:

> Z64 encoding do the following:
> • Compress the data using the LZ77 algorithm.
> • Encode the compressed data using the MIME Base64 algorithm.
> • Calculate a CRC across the encoded data.
> • Add a unique header to differentiate the new format from the existing ASCII hexadecimal encoding.

Below is part of the label I am trying to decode back to human readable form just the same way the printer does.

```
^XA
^MMT
^PW709
^LL0472
^LS0
^FO256,288^GFA,04992,04992,00052,:Z64:
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:BB36
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

I tried to use python code like below just to decode this line "eJztlL9uHDcQxoegExYp(...)fLrEEkssscQS/8/4BE9yVVQ=" so i stripped the ZPL language coding which is :Z64: prefix and :BB36 CRC output.

```
import zlib
import base64


def decode_base64_and_inflate(b64string):
    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(b64string)
    return zlib.decompress(decoded_data, 0)
```

Output I get is as such:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xff\xf8\x7f\xff\x80\x00>\x03\xe0\xfe\x00\xf3\xf8\x07\x80?\x8e\x00\x00\x03\xfe\x00\x0f\xf8\x00\xfe\x00\x00\x0f\xff\x8f\x80>\x00\x00\xf8\x00>\xff\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xff\xf8\x7f\xff\xc0\x00?\x03\xc1\xff\x80w\xfc\x07\x80\x7f\xde\x00\x00\x07\xfe\x00?\xfc\x01\xff\x80\x00\x1f\xff\x87\xc0<\x00\x00\xf8\x00\x1e\xff\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xff\xf8\xff\xff\xc0\x00?\x83\xe3\xff\xc0\xff\xfe\x0f\x80\xff\xfe\x00\x00\x1f\xff\x80\xff\xfe\x03\xff\xc0\x00\x1f\xff\x8f\xe0>\x00\x00\xf8\x00>\xff\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x07\xff\xf0\x7f\xff\xc0\x00\x1f\x03\xc3\xff\xc0\x7f\x7f\x07\x81\xff\xfe\x00\x00\x1f\xff\x00\x7f\xfc\x07\xff\xc0\x00\x1f\xff\x07\xe0>\x00\x00|\x00<\x7f\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xff\xf8\x7f\xff\xc0\x00\x0f\x83\xe3\xef\xe0\xfe?\x0f\x83\xff\xfe\x00\x00?\xbf\x80\xfe\xbe\x0f\xef\xe0\x00\x0f\xff\x83\xf0>\x00\x00\xfc\x00>\xff\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xf0\x00\x0f\xc0\x00\x0f\xc3\xc3\x03\xf0|\x1f\x07\x81\xf0~\x00\x00>\x0f\x81\xf8\x04\x0f\x83\xf0\x00\x00\x0f\x81\xf0<\x00\x00|\x00|\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xf8\x00\x1f\x80\x00\x0f\xc3\xe2\x03\xf0\xf8\x0f\x8f\x83\xf0>\x00\x00>\x0f\xc3\xf8\x00\x0f\x83\xf0\x00\x00\x0f\x81\xf8>\x00\x00~\x00\xfc\x00\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xe0\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x07\xc7\xc0\x01\xf0p\x0f\x07\x83\xe0>\x00\x00|\x07\xc1\xf0\x00\x1f\x01\xf0\x00\x00\x07\x00\xf8>\x00\x00\x7fU\xfc\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xe0\x00>\x00\x00\x03\xe3\xe0\x00\xf0\xf8\x0f\x0f\x83\xe0>\x00\x00|\x07\xe3\xe0\x00\x1f\x01\xf0\x00\x00\x0f\x80\xfc>\x00\x00?\xff\xf8\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\xc0\x00|\x00\x00\x01\xf3\xc0\x01\xf0x\x1f\x07\x83\xc0\x1e\x00\x00|\x07\xc1\xf0\x00\x1f\x01\xf0\x00\x00\x0f\x80|<\x00\x00?\xff\xf8\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x80\x00\xfc\x03\xfe\x03\xfb\xe0\x01\xf8\xff\xfe\x0f\x83\xe0>\x0f\xf8\xf8\x03\xe3\xe0\x00?\x01\xf8\xff\x80\x0f\x80\xfe>\x0f\xf8?\xff\xf8\x00\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x00\x01\xf8\x03\xff\x01\xf3\xc0\x01\xf0\x7f\xfc\x07\x83\xc0\x1e\x0f\xfc|\x03\xc1\xf0\x00\x1f\x00\xf0\xff\xc0\x07\x00>>\x0f\xfc\x1f\xff\xf0\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x00~\x00\x03\xf8\x03\xfe\x00\xff\xe0\x00\xf8\xff\xf8\x0f\x83\xe0>\x0f\xf8\xf8\x03\xe3\xf0\x00>\x00\xf8\xff\x80\x0f\x80?>\x0f\xf8?\x00\xf0\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x03\xf0\x03\xff\x00\x7f\xc0\x01\xf0\x7f\xc0\x07\x83\xc0\x1e\x0f\xfcx\x03\xc1\xf8\x00\x1f\x01\xf0\xff\xc0\x0f\x80\x1f<\x0f\xfc\x1f\x01\xf0\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfc\x00\x0f\xe0\x03\xba\x00\xfb\xe0\x01\xf8\xf8\x00\x0f\x83\xe0>\x0b\xb8\xf8\x03\xe1\xfe\x88>\x00\xf8\xbb\x80\x0f\x80\x1f\xbe\x0b\xb8\x0f\x81\xe0\x00\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x01\xf8\x00\x07\xc0\x00\x00\x01\xf7\xc0\x01\xf0p\x00\x07\x83\xe0\x1e\x00\x00|\x07\xc1\xff\xfc\x1e\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x07\x00\x07\xfe\x00\x00\x0f\x01\xe0\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x03\xf8\x00\x0f\x80\x00\x00\x03\xe3\xe0\x03\xf0\xf8\x00\x0f\x83\xe0>\x00\x00\xf8\x03\xe0\xff\xfc>\x00\xf8\x00\x00\x0f\x80\x0f\xfe\x00\x00\x0f\x83\xe0\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x01\xf0\x00\x1f\x80\x00\x00\x03\xc3\xc1\x01\xf0x\x00\x07\x81\xf0~\x00\x00|\x03\xc0\x7f\xfc\x1f\x01\xf0\x00\x00\x0f\x80\x07\xfc\x00\x00\x07\x83\xc0\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x03\xf0\x00\x1f\x80\x00\x00\x0f\xe3\xe3\x8f\xe0\xfc\x0e\x0f\x83\xf8\xfe\x00\x00\xf8\x03\xe0?\xfc>\x00\xf8\x00\x00\x0f\x80\x0f\xbe\x00\x00\x0f\xc3\xe0\x00\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x03\xe0\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x07\xc3\xc3\xff\xc0\x7f~\x07\x81\xff\xfe\x00\x00|\x03\xc0\x00<\x1e\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x07\x00\x1f>\x00\x00\x07\xc3\xc0\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x07\xe0\x00?\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x83\xe3\xff\xe0\x7f\xfe\x0f\x80\xff\xfe\x00\x00\xf8\x03\xe0\x00<>\x00\xf8\x00\x00\x0f\x80?>\x00\x00\x07\xe3\xc0\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x07\xc0\x00?\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x03\xc1\xff\x80?\xfc\x07\x80\xff\xde\x00\x00|\x07\xc0\x00<\x1f\x01\xf0\x00\x00\x0f\x80><\x00\x00\x03\xc7\x80\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xe0\x00?\x80\x00\x00?\x83\xe1\xff\x80?\xf8\x0f\x80\xff\xbe\x00\x00\xfc\x07\xc0\x00<?\x01\xf8\x00\x00\x0f\x80~>\x00\x00\x03\xef\x80\x00\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x07\xe0\x00?\x00\x00\x00\x04\x07\xc0|\x00\x07\xc0\x07\x80\x1c\x1e\x00\x00|\x07\xc0\x00<\x1f\x01\xf0\x00\x00\x07\x00|>\x00\x00\x03\xe7\x00\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x07\xe0\x00?\x80\x80\x00\x00\x03\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x80\x00>\x00\x00~\x07\xc0\x00<\x1f\x83\xf0\x00\x00\x0f\x80\xf8>\x00\x00\x03\xef\x80\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x07\xf00?\x81\x80\x00\x00\x03\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x1e\x00\x00|\x07\x80\x00<\x1f\x81\xf0\x00\x00\x0f\x81\xf8<\x00\x00\x01\xff\x00\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x07\xfb\xf8?\xef\x80\x00\x00\x03\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x80\x00>\x00\x00>\x0f\x80\xff\xfc\x0f\x83\xe0\x00\x00\x0f\x83\xf8>\x00\x00\x01\xff\x80\x00\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x03\xff\xf0\x1f\xff\xc0\x00\x00\x03\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x1e\x00\x00?\xff\x00\xff\xfc\x07\xff\xc0\x00\x00\x07\x01\xf0>\x00\x00\x01\xff\x00\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x03\xff\xf8\x1f\xff\x80\x00\x00\x03\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x80\x00>\x00\x00?\xff\x00\xff\xfc\x0f\xff\xe0\x00\x00\x0f\x83\xe0>\x00\x00\x00\xfe\x00\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x01\xff\xf0\x0f\xff\x80\x00\x00\x03\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x1f\xfe\x00\xff\xfc\x07\xff\x80\x00\x00\x0f\x87\xc0<\x00\x00\x00\xfe\x00\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xe0\x0f\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x03\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x80\x00>\x00\x00\x0f\xfe\x00\xff\xfc\x03\xff\x80\x00\x00\x0f\x8f\xe0>\x00\x00\x00\xfe\x00\x00\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x7f\x00\x01\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x07\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x01\xf0\x00D@\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x05\x01\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00T\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x80\x00>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

When run the original label code through [Labelary viewer](https://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&quality=grayscale&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&rotation=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5EMMT%0A%5EPW709%0A%5ELL0472%0A%5ELS0%0A%5EFO256%2C288%5EGFA%2C04992%2C04992%2C00052%2C%3AZ64%3A%0AeJztlL9uHDcQxoegExYp6MKlIr6GgayXKvwISZ9HSHnF4sTDFTbg4l7HgIAzDypUOl3K0LgipRi4ISCG45lZniMJNpIyCHYEaKXlfvzxmz8EWGKJJZZY4j8WF195b4vHBBrD8wbZHI9phDI2fSwAutEqNPoGd2EEKDBiYY0nTQSD8QWq7P68zgOsvsfNTQUwDXxVGMDhqziw5hwra1A4FtMPGIq%2FOxbieNze0vYOAzZNOzrcpc4RzWVljcFMuOzwwBz3%2B4EXHdKqEY1hzQTDpWjac9Z8q1lT%2FLsknFfHRhz%2FLrS9veVTbDNpaueoTOeO%2FPTmkNcuVuboQ%2FEAo92UJ3ZLX9gN4YnDP5SbRG9IQ8myqaxtqpw3Sptorgt0DeFhTaTaNS7QH78MJubJxIk45%2FqQHe1LZHByEmDN5U%2F1M8cH4ehUqk4jc8wxieaYZo0NhAdP1RENnctzLlYDbT7p6IhzZg7pAccGwj%2FQNIVvroRTdPJ7qU9yO%2FqPOF4VDDa0kRumiB%2FO2aTQYBl0FM5EeUOVnK2TZg5kjAbG0VaHWTjmfYKicYcnjm3EafS0zMlA9pjjmQNdg1llhZY54sdU4vwqnBWVif1gtMENxFGzhj7WRV3tXp%2FyZvecV53cm7dFf2iviXNFHLf%2F7q3dpNkPVpO4AKf6UN7KOaieN6znIPUxPBIqzWe7E40NzMlrM9cHqP2oZDohtwUvW9ZsuyZOnDoTsvixcRgUc7h3yN1l7fUxPE%2FbOPuJjdvNHsQP9XUbaQq3W%2B5rrtZnzp5%2BX3c%2FcWKNofmk%2BtA8TIMv7jeZH%2BLA0P24kT%2BK%2FWyjpXbTmISDND%2B%2B0LzgzIGhczxrjifNwG2tMLIf95Hm1K8sboRDTofuZ6R%2B0zeh%2BxllFDAwx36k%2B2Bc2aZvaffKGuo31qyJo2%2FDyY9ozri3s7mJF8MZDa36EO9zDEys%2BQP6%2FKxd%2BLnfdYXHaYQ%2BVrAWjcxpKJ0zz8LkYpwltCNnSv5kzWQCaTbzbA9sunNycXfpyxzKKFYuPnUAc%2Fh6lHvnL8ps58AjjkdAud%2FAqDz%2BzVFImq9wRCOrBOPX7aTJ5sR57Mc14VBardzXJw1g0vz2SxzLGlm1uxNH7l7Xn7Mfc59D3JcXsvM3Cp7R40eAp%2FAo8kPOv4p7fuI%2FfLrEEkssscQS%2F8%2F4BE9yVVQ%3D%3ABB36%0A%5EPQ1%2C0%2C1%2C%5EXZ) it shows as text with some special charactes. How do I calculate this compressed text back to human readable form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit .prn file for printing it in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59251099/edit-prn-file-for-printing-it-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Okay I think it does partially. It seems that what I want to achieve can not be done as text is converted into bitmap in ZPL. I will try to confirm this information with Zebra technicians.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this method to create the PNG:

https://codeutility.org/javascript-convert-zpl-base64-in-image-png-stack-overflow/

[image]